# Action including a fill layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions, script

I'm operating in Windows on CC2019.

I'm writing an action in which I include a layer fill. I want it so that when I run the action it fills the layer with the foreground colour I have selected at the time of the running the action each time I run it.

But whenever I record the action, it embeds the colour value of the foreground colour (say 100% cyan) at the time of recording it. So everytime I run it subsequently it fills with 100% cyan no matter what foreground colour is selected.

I know I can put a modal control in there so you can select the colour manually, but running action 100s of times I'd rather avoid that happening.

Does anyone have a way around this? I'm open to using JavaScript but I wouldn't have the skill to write it myself.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can't replicate this problem in Photoshop. If I record an action to fill with the foreground colour using Edit > Fill > and choose "Foreground colour", stop the recording, then I change the foreground colour, then run the action, it uses the currently selected foreground colour.

Comment: Thanks Billy. It was the layer fill I was trying to make work not the fill (why they named two things the same is beyond me). But Danielillo has solved the issue below anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the *include a layer fill* in the action, add this command with the following shortcut:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> (Fill with the foreground color)

[image]